# Working with different versions of a project, that has been built with different versions of Typescript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I'm currently part of a team that is working on a rather large Typescript project in Visual Studio. As time has gone by and different versions of the project has been released, we've run into a snag when it comes to the versioning of Typescript installed together with Visual Studio.

**Scenario**:

- v 1.1.0 of product released, built on TypeScript 1.8
- v 1.2.0 of product released, built on TypeScript 2.1

A bug from customer X is reported for the 1.1.0 version, and the team will start working on a fix.

**Problem**:

Visual Studio is currently configured to use the latest version of TypeScript (2.1 in this case), so the code from v 1.1.0 does not compile.

Yes, I can manually change typescript versions in the project file and move around on tsc.exe to make this work. Typescript is installed globally as well, but for some reason, they decided that Visual Studio will install the compiler in its own folder instead of acessing the globally installed one.

Hoping someone else has run into this problem, and have a better approach to this.

Comment: Are you using git for source control? If you checkout the 1.1.0 version of the app, isn't typescript version 1.8 in the project file?

Comment: Yes, we're using git for source control, but this does not fix the problem as you suggested. I did, however, find a solution. Will add an answer to my own question, unless anything else will be proposed

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by adding the following parameter to my .csproj file:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompiledBlocked>
```

Ended up running a grunt watch task, using the globally installed TypeScript compiler to compile the project.

Fetched from the [official TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html)

> If you are using a different build tool to build your project (e.g. gulp, grunt , etc.) and VS for the development and debugging experience, set true in your project. This should give you all the editing support, but not the build when you hit F5.

Comment: That's cool. So you get ts compile output in the task runner window?

Comment: I could do that, yes. I just tend to run the tasks in a separate command line window :)